# Clarification on IPhone Memory management(autorelease)

Tags: iphone, memory-management, autorelease

I know a similar question has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684552/objective-c-returning-allocd-memory-in-a-function-bad), but I just want to make sure I understand it a little bit better.  Here is my scenario...

I have a helper class method that is returning an allocated UIImageView, as seen below.

```
+(UIImageView *)tableCellButton{
 return [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]] autorelease];
```

}

Then, in one of my UIViewController methods I am using it as such..

```
UIImageView *imageView = [Helper tableCellButton];
imageView.frame = cell.backgroundView.bounds;
imageView.tag = 250;
[cell.backgroundView addSubview:imageView];
```

My question is in regards to how this memory is released.  I am not using an autorelease pool(other than the application created one), and the variable is not an iVar/Property(so it won't get released when dealloc is called). In this case am I responsible for releasing the memory after I have called it?  When does autorelease come into play? Thanks for the help!

Comment: See this question here about when the [AutoreleasePool Releases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581828/autorelease-scope).  Hopefully that will give you some insight.  You never have to `release` and object which is `auto-released.`  It will likely only persist through the "event" if it gets created during a button-press, or as long as `cell.backgroundView` persists (`addSubview` retains.)

Comment: right on the release... So, the only autorelease pool in my application is the one that resides in main.  Since that is the case, does that cause a leak, or will that object get sent a release when the ViewController cleans up the table and cells?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  I also found the memory management docs for iOS(don't know how I missed them before).  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `autorelease` will cause `release` to be sent to the object the next time through the event loop. That will account for the `alloc` call you make in `tableCellButton`. The only other time the object is retained is inside of `addSubview`, which will also handle its own `release` of the same object. Based on the code above, then, you memory management of this object checks out.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of the runloop has its own autorelease pool.

Essentially, think of it like this:

```
while(1)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [someObject doSomething];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: When the application is running is there an autorelease pool created for each event, or there just the one global in main?

Comment: Every event. That means, when the event is done, the autorelease pool is drained, and a new one is created. There's an autorelease pool in main, but that's basically a final catchall before the end of the program.